# Copy a file between containers

Tags: podman

I'm looking for a way to copy a file from container A to container B within a Dockerfile.

Inside the Dokerfile I write this code but it fails:

```
COPY containersource:/mypath/filename.properties containerdest:/path/cfg/
```

Comment: In a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)?

Comment: Hi, no in the Dockerfile I have junst one FROM command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy from container *image* to container *image*, you write in the dockerfile

```
FROM fedora:rawhide as source
FROM fedora:38
COPY --from=source /etc/fedora-release /path/cfg/
```

If indeed you want to copy from *container* to *container*, you use

```bash
podman cp containersource:/mypath/filename.properties containerdest:/path/cfg/
```